# Inserting XML fragments into an XML document with lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, merge, lxml

I have a set of XML files that I want to merge together.  There's the master XML document which is a full ISO 19139 XML document, and two other XML files that may contain `<gmd:descriptiveKeywords>` elements.  I need to extract any of these `<gmd:descriptiveKeywords>` elements from the fragment files and add to the master.  There are hundreds of these sets of files, so I need to do some matching to make sure I'm combining the right set of data.

A fragment XML file might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ValueSupplyChain xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="MICA_B1v-101"
    title="MINERALS4EU-EU MINERALS KNOWLEDGE DATA PLATFORM (EU-MKDP)">
    <gmd:descriptiveKeywords>
        <gmd:MD_Keywords id="exploration">
            <gmd:keyword>
                <gco:CharacterString>Exploration</gco:CharacterString>
            </gmd:keyword>
            <gmd:thesaurusName>
                <gmd:CI_Citation>
                    <gmd:title>
                        <gco:CharacterString>MICA ontology
                            (ValueSupplyChainScheme)</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:title>
                    <gmd:date gco:nilReason="unknown"/>
                    <gmd:edition>
                        <gco:CharacterString>2</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:edition>
                    <gmd:identifier>
                        <gmd:MD_Identifier>
                            <gmd:code>
                                <gmx:Anchor
                                    xlink:href="https://w3id.org/mica/ontology/MicaOntology/7418a9ae1cd44847889c2c92408e1e71"
                                />
                            </gmd:code>
                        </gmd:MD_Identifier>
                    </gmd:identifier>
                </gmd:CI_Citation>
            </gmd:thesaurusName>
        </gmd:MD_Keywords>
    </gmd:descriptiveKeywords>
</ValueSupplyChain>
```

The master XML has a structure like below (using an image as the XML can get quite large):

[image: ISO XML document structure]

Ideally I would like to append the relevant fragment sections below the existing keyword sections, and create a new master document.

My problem is that although I seem to be able match the correct sets of data, and find the relevant section, changes *I think* I'm making never get written to the output destination file.

My code is:

```
import logging
import platform
import glob
import os
from lxml import etree as et

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

PC_name = platform.node()
if PC_name == 'blah ':
    root_directory = "blah\\blah\\outputs\\"
    dir_sep = "\\"
else:
    root_directory = "C:\\Temp\\"
    dir_sep = "\\"

batch_directory_name = "Batch1"
batch_number = "1"
in_directory = root_directory + batch_directory_name
out_directory_name = "splodge"
out_directory = in_directory + dir_sep + out_directory_name

if not os.path.exists(out_directory):
    os.makedirs(out_directory)

os.chdir(in_directory)

fileSuffix = ".xml"
globDirSep = "/"
fileTStem = "T" + batch_number + "_"
fileDStem = "D" + batch_number + "_"
fileVStem = "V" + batch_number + "_"
fileTPattern = fileTStem + "[0-9]*" + fileSuffix
globTPattern = in_directory + globDirSep + fileTPattern
stem = in_directory + dir_sep + fileTStem

ns_all = {'gmd': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd',
          'gco': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco',
          'gmx': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx',
          'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
          'gml': 'http://www.opengis.net/gml',
          'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
          'geonet': 'http://www.fao.org/geonetwork'}

record_title = \
    'gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title/gco:CharacterString'
record_keywords = 'gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:descriptiveKeywords'

for file in glob.glob(globTPattern):
    'Get the record number of the current T file'
    fnum = file.replace(stem, "").replace(fileSuffix, "")
    tree = et.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    recordT = root.find(record_title, ns_all)
    'We want to use the UPPER case version to compare with D and V file titles'
    RecordTitle = recordT.text.upper()
    logging.debug("T title: " + RecordTitle)
    dFile = in_directory + dir_sep + fileDStem + fnum + fileSuffix
    vFile = in_directory + dir_sep + fileVStem + fnum + fileSuffix
    'Find keyword sections in T file (and how many for interest...)'
    keywordList = root.findall(record_keywords, ns_all)
    knum = len(keywordList)
    logging.debug("T file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: " + str(knum))

    try:
        dTree = et.parse(dFile)
        dRoot = dTree.getroot()
        recordDT = dRoot.attrib['title']
        logging.debug("D title: " + recordDT)

        if RecordTitle == recordDT:
            logging.debug("T and D titles are the same, we can continue...")
            'If the titles match then we can insert the D keywords fragment'
            DKeywords = dRoot.findall('gmd:descriptiveKeywords', ns_all)
            dnum = len(DKeywords)
            logging.debug("D file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: " + str(dnum))
            keywordList.extend(DKeywords)
            logging.debug("Subtotal: " + str(len(keywordList)))
        else:
            logging.debug("T and D titles don't match")

    except:
        logging.debug("Cannot parse: " + dFile)

    try:
        vTree = et.parse(vFile)
        vRoot = vTree.getroot()
        recordVT = vRoot.attrib['title']
        logging.debug("V title: " + recordVT)

        if RecordTitle == recordVT:
            logging.debug("T and V titles are the same, we can continue...")
            'If the titles match then we can insert the V keywords fragment'

            VKeywords = vRoot.findall('gmd:descriptiveKeywords', ns_all)
            vnum = len(VKeywords)
            logging.debug("V file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: " + str(vnum))
            keywordList.extend(VKeywords)
            logging.debug("Subtotal: " + str(len(keywordList)))

        else:
            logging.debug("T and V titles don't match")

    except:
        logging.debug("Cannot parse: " + vFile)

    newFile = "out" + batch_number + "_" + fnum + fileSuffix
    writeTo = out_directory_name + dir_sep + newFile
    tree.write(writeTo)
```

and the debug output is like:

```
DEBUG:root:T title: BGR BOREHOLE MAP
DEBUG:root:T file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: 7
DEBUG:root:D title: BGR BOREHOLE MAP
DEBUG:root:T and D titles are the same, we can continue...
DEBUG:root:D file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: 5
DEBUG:root:Subtotal: 12
DEBUG:root:V title: BGR BOREHOLE MAP
DEBUG:root:T and V titles are the same, we can continue...
DEBUG:root:V file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: 1
DEBUG:root:Subtotal: 13
DEBUG:root:T title: 3D, 4D AND PREDICTIVE MODELLING OF MAJOR MINERAL BELTS IN EUROPE
DEBUG:root:T file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: 36
DEBUG:root:D title: 3D, 4D AND PREDICTIVE MODELLING OF MAJOR MINERAL BELTS IN EUROPE
DEBUG:root:T and D titles are the same, we can continue...
DEBUG:root:D file has the following number of gmd:descriptiveKeywords sections: 5
DEBUG:root:Subtotal: 41
```

From the debug info it appears that I am successfully adding to the gmd:descriptiveKeywords elements, well the the list length increments as expected, but as I say when I write out the XML I'm getting the content of the original master file.

I tried too with ElementTree, but I had the same issue; furthermore the output doesn't honour the namespace prefixes used in the master.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Minimal code to reproduce the issue is below:

```
from lxml import etree as et

# Open the master file, which is a well-formed and schema valid ISO 19139 XML record
tree = et.parse('T1_0.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

ns_all = {'gmd': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd',
          'gco': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco',
          'gmx': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx',
          'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
          'gml': 'http://www.opengis.net/gml',
          'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
          'geonet': 'http://www.fao.org/geonetwork'}

keywordList = root.findall('gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:descriptiveKeywords', ns_all)

# Just a quick check that everything works as expected
print(len(keywordList)) # Should return 7 for the master file

# Open a well-formed XML file containing content we wish to add to the (or a copy of the) master record
dTree = et.parse('D1_0.xml')
dRoot = dTree.getroot()
DKeywords = dRoot.findall('gmd:descriptiveKeywords', ns_all)

# Just a quick check that everything works as expected
print(len(DKeywords)) # Should return 5 for the D file

# Add the keywords from the second file to the keywords of the master file
keywordList.extend(DKeywords)

# We've added 5 records so the result should be 12
print(len(keywordList)) # I get 12 here

# Write out the new file
tree.write('combinedTD1_0.xml')

# If all worked as expected the new file should have 12
ctree = et.parse('combinedTD1_0.xml')
croot = ctree.getroot()
CKeywords = croot.findall('gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:descriptiveKeywords', ns_all)

print(len(CKeywords)) # I get 7 :(
```

The files are:

Master file example: [T1_0.xml](https://pastebin.com/yJN2rM4B)

Fragment file example: [D1_0.xml](https://pastebin.com/iABftYzN)

Fragment file example: [V1_0.xml](https://pastebin.com/dhsCDzb1)

Comment: You have a lot of code that does not seem relevant to the main problem. I think you need to trim the question down to something simpler that we can easily reproduce (a [mcve]).

Comment: @mzjn You are correct of course, I have now given the minimal, complete code to reproduce the error and provided links to the input files.

Comment: @user27874 the intention is to have _only_ the minimal code, not additionally :)

Comment: @Elazar, possibly both meta questions, but perhaps the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve page should be edited to convey that intention?   Also interested in why you edited the tags, isn't this a merge issue?

Comment: @user27874 the merge can be returned, but I don't think it's likely to help. I've removed it because that tag `python` is more important (you need both `python` and `python-3.x`) and there were too many.

Comment: As for the other question, I think it's common sense - try to look at it as someone that tries to answer. Walls of text are confusing, at least for me. The shorter the code, the easier to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Can you open up one the *descriptiveKeywords* tags in master XML? What does its structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keywordList.extend(DKeywords)` just adds elements to a list. This operation does not do anything with the XML tree.

To insert the additional `descriptiveKeywords` nodes as siblings of the ones in the master document, you can do as follows:

```
# Get the last of the descriptiveKeywords nodes in the master document
last_kw = keywordList[-1]
# Get the node's parent and its position (index) within the parent
kw_parent = last_kw.getparent()
ix = kw_parent.index(last_kw)

# Insert the descriptiveKeyword nodes from the fragment file as successive siblings
for dk in DKeywords:
    kw_parent.insert(ix+1, dk)
    ix += 1
```

Comment: Had one of those palm hits forehead moments, as soon as I read the first line.  I can confirm this fixes my problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I have answered many, many times, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, when needing to manipulate XML files like merging documents. Python's `lxml` module can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Specifically, XSLT maintains the `document()` function which you can pass a file name parameter to append fragment nodes to existing master nodes. Also, XSLT uses the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy entire document as is with [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to index document by distinct *keywords*. With this approach the only `for` loop needed is to iterate through files.

Because OP does not set up a reproducible example, below is an example demonstration using StackOverflow's top 3 users in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) and [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) tags. Master file begins with the top 1 rank. The Python script then iterates to append 2nd rank and then 3rd rank by `<tag1>`:

**Master XML** *(top 1 rank users)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stackoverflow>
  <group lang="python">
    <topusers>
      <user>Martijn Pieters</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters</link>
      <location>Cambridge, United Kingdom </location>
      <year_rep>70,404</year_rep>
      <total_rep>590,309</total_rep>
      <tag1>python</tag1>
      <tag2>python-3.x</tag2>
      <tag3>python-2.7</tag3>
    </topusers>
  </group>
  <group lang="xslt">
    <topusers>
      <user>Dimitre Novatchev</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev</link>
      <location>United States</location>
      <year_rep>9,922</year_rep>
      <total_rep>197,245</total_rep>
      <tag1>xslt</tag1>
      <tag2>xml</tag2>
      <tag3>xpath</tag3>
    </topusers>
  </group>
</stackoverflow>
```

**Rank 2 XML** *(i.e., fragment)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stackoverflow>
 <group lang="python">
      <topusers>
        <user>Alex Martelli</user>
        <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli</link>
        <location>Sunnyvale, CA</location>
        <year_rep>49,172</year_rep>
        <total_rep>540,372</total_rep>
        <tag1>python</tag1>
        <tag2>list</tag2>
        <tag3>c++</tag3>
      </topusers>
  </group>
  <group lang="python">
      <topusers>
        <user>Martin Honnen</user>
        <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen</link>
        <location>Germany</location>
        <year_rep>10,046</year_rep>
        <total_rep>92,604</total_rep>
        <tag1>xslt</tag1>
        <tag2>xml</tag2>
        <tag3>xpath</tag3>
      </topusers>  
  </group>
</stackoverflow>
```

**Rank 3 XML** *(i.e., fragment)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stackoverflow>  
 <group lang="python">
     <topusers>
        <user>unutbu</user>
        <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu</link>
        <location></location>
        <year_rep>55,492</year_rep>
        <total_rep>453,267</total_rep>
        <tag1>python</tag1>
        <tag2>pandas</tag2>
        <tag3>numpy</tag3>
      </topusers>    
  </group>
 <group lang="xslt">
      <topusers>
        <user>michael.hor257k</user>
        <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k</link>
        <location></location>
        <year_rep>11,339</year_rep>
        <total_rep>70,473</total_rep>
        <tag1>xslt</tag1>
        <tag2>xml</tag2>
        <tag3>xslt-1.0</tag3>
      </topusers>  
  </group>
</stackoverflow>
```

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file in same directory as .xml files)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit_xml_declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="keyid" match="topusers" use="tag1" />  
  <xsl:param name="fragment" /> 

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- IMPORT XML FRAGMENT -->
  <xsl:template match="group">     
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="topusers[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyid', tag1))]"/>  
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- COPY EXISTING topusers AND APPEND EXTERNAL topusers BY SAME KEYWORD -->
  <xsl:template match="topusers">     
    <xsl:variable select="tag1" name="keyword"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('keyid', tag1)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- PASS PYTHON PARAM INTO document() -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($fragment)/stackoverflow/group/topusers[tag1=$keyword]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(parses all xml and xsl files)*

```
import os
import lxml.etree as et

# CURRENT DIRECTORY OF SCRIPT
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
master = os.path.join(cd, 'Master.xml')

# LOAD XSL SCRIPT
xsl = et.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'XSLTScript.xsl'))
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)

# ITERATE THROUGH FRAGMENT XML FILES IN DIRECTORY
for f in sorted(os.listdir(cd)):
    if f.endswith('.xml'):
        # LOAD MASTER XML
        doc = et.parse(master)

        print(f)
        # PASS FILE NAME AS PARAMETER FOR XSLT's document()
        n = et.XSLT.strparam(f)
        result = transform(doc, fragment=n)

        # UPDATE MASTER XML
        with open(master, 'wb') as s:
            s.write(result)
```

**Output** *(top 3 ranks each tag)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stackoverflow>
  <group lang="python">
    <topusers>
      <user>Martijn Pieters</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters</link>
      <location>Cambridge, United Kingdom </location>
      <year_rep>70,404</year_rep>
      <total_rep>590,309</total_rep>
      <tag1>python</tag1>
      <tag2>python-3.x</tag2>
      <tag3>python-2.7</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>Alex Martelli</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli</link>
      <location>Sunnyvale, CA</location>
      <year_rep>49,172</year_rep>
      <total_rep>540,372</total_rep>
      <tag1>python</tag1>
      <tag2>list</tag2>
      <tag3>c++</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>unutbu</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu</link>
      <location/>
      <year_rep>55,492</year_rep>
      <total_rep>453,267</total_rep>
      <tag1>python</tag1>
      <tag2>pandas</tag2>
      <tag3>numpy</tag3>
    </topusers>
  </group>
  <group lang="xslt">
    <topusers>
      <user>Dimitre Novatchev</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev</link>
      <location>United States</location>
      <year_rep>9,922</year_rep>
      <total_rep>197,245</total_rep>
      <tag1>xslt</tag1>
      <tag2>xml</tag2>
      <tag3>xpath</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>Martin Honnen</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen</link>
      <location>Germany</location>
      <year_rep>10,046</year_rep>
      <total_rep>92,604</total_rep>
      <tag1>xslt</tag1>
      <tag2>xml</tag2>
      <tag3>xpath</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>michael.hor257k</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k</link>
      <location/>
      <year_rep>11,339</year_rep>
      <total_rep>70,473</total_rep>
      <tag1>xslt</tag1>
      <tag2>xml</tag2>
      <tag3>xslt-1.0</tag3>
    </topusers>
  </group>
</stackoverflow>
```

---

OP **XSLT**

The corresponding XSLT to fit OP's actual master and fragment files may look like this untested version. Below assumes *keyword* is in same layout as posted fragement (unable to tell since image closes the `<gmd:descriptiveKeywords>` nodes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
                              xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
                              xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                              xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit_xml_declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="keyid" match="gmd:MD_Keywords" use="gmd:keyword/gco:CharacterString" />  
  <xsl:param name="fragment" /> 

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- IMPORT XML FRAGMENT -->
  <xsl:template match="gmd:descriptiveKeywords">     
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="gmd:MD_Keywords[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyid', gmd:keyword/gco:CharacterString))]"/>  
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- COPY EXISTING gmd:MD_Keywords AND APPEND EXTERNAL gmd:MD_Keywords BY SAME KEYWORD -->
  <xsl:template match="gmd:MD_Keywords">     
    <xsl:variable select="gmd:keyword/gco:CharacterString" name="keyword"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('keyid', gmd:keyword/gco:CharacterString)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- PASS PYTHON PARAM INTO document() -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($fragment)/ValueSupplyChain/gmd:descriptiveKeywords/gmd:MD_Keywords[gmd:keyword/gco:CharacterString=$keyword]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I thought I provided a reproduceable example by providing the files T1_0.xml as master and V1_0.xml and/or D1_0.xml as fragments, but perhaps T1 was too big.  I've up voted this because I had also started looking at XSLT and had already got as far as discovering `document()` and `template match="@*|node()` elsewhere but somehow duplicating my fragments :o to get close to what I was after.  This though is comprehensive

Comment: I was about to ask what those files were as they have no distinguishing labels. Also, what is the keyword? `gmd:MD_Keywords/@id`? `gmd:keyword/gco:CharacterString`? I am not finding exact matches with those examples.

Comment: The attribute I want to match on is the title in the parent element of the fragments, so in my fuller code I was using `recordDT = dRoot.attrib['title']` and that needs to match with the title of the master file at location `gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title/gco:CharacterString`  If they match then the `<gmd:descriptiveKeywords>` sections of the fragment should be added to the master.  Sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: Your XMLs are bit complex. I only see *BGR Borehole map* as the matching titles in examples (which faces case sensitivity) and in Master this reference is toward the top in abstract with no `descriptiveKeywords` near (so not sure where appending should go) Plus both fragments have different roots. But make no mistake -XSLT is still viable here.

Comment: In fact, I even have to thank you as this is the first time I ever sent a parameter from application layer (Python) to XSLT script, similar to a parameterized query from application layer to SQL statement! It may not help you but this is certainly going in my library and maybe helps future readers.